# how to put two different map collections into two different excel template sheets of the same template using jxls

Tags: java, jxls

I have two queries results as List or Map and they have to put into two different template sheets in the same excel template,

Could some one help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Apache poi is best solution for this case
[For more info](https://poi.apache.org)

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a bit? Just dropping a link might not be that helpful.

Comment: Could you please tell me the solution using jxls api

Comment: Have two pojo class entities and result of each pojo class to be put in to two excel template sheets of the same excel

Comment: @Kammalokesh Sorry for the delay. Apache POI is not a jxls. But you can create and modify the excel file using apache poi api. This is a open-source api developed by apache software foundation